# Image Sizes for Themes

Tags: java, ios, codenameone

I'm looking at making my own theme in CodenameOne but I cant find out quite what I need to do (I should point out I'm new to codename one)

From what I can see the key to what I need to do revolves around Multi-Images. I place an image there and the designer scales it multiple times so that I have all the images needed for the multitude of devices. Clearly, if it's scaling, the exact size of the image I put in Multi Image is a little irrelevant but what is the optimum size (presumably the close to the largest dimensions that will be used?). Can anyone give me an idea about the resolution of, say, a background image that I'm going to put into Multi Image and the correct (or best) aspect ratio?

Answer (score 0):

Historically we recommended making retina iPhone sized images then importing them using the "Quick Add Multi Image" menu option and picking "Very High" as the target DPI.

This still works rather well but recently there has been an influx of higher DPI devices (iPhone 6+ and newer Android flagships) so we might update that guideline in the near future.